# Load average is high, CPU usage is low, what's going on?

Tags: cpu, performance, raspberry-pi, docker, cpu-usage

I'm running Docker on a `RPi3B+`, with only 4 containers so far: Portainer, PiHole, NGINX Proxy Manager and its database. Some slowdowns (a delay after entering a command on the CLI) have caused me to open up `htop` and keep an eye on it. According to `htop`, my Load average is slightly over 4, so more than the quad-core processor can handle, if I understand correctly. The thing is though, the processor bars are rarely above 5%, and the process that takes up the most CPU % (sorted the list by CPU%) is `htop` itself most of the time.

What's going on here? Is the load from Docker's containers not properly displayed in the CPU% load? Is the load average wrong? I'd love to see if I can improve performance, but when `htop` says the most CPU intensive thing is itself, it's not easy to troubleshoot.

One suggestion I've seen a few times is that many programs will be waiting for I/O. If I understand correclty, this should be shown as a `D` state in `htop`. I rarely see more than 2 programs in that state.

CPU load average in this screenshot is now relatively low, it has been very slowly decreasing over time. Before it was usually between 4.5 and 8.

**`HTOP`**
[image]

Another screenshot, of `vmstat 1` this time, as suggested by Charles Duffy. I haven't got a clue what to read from this, maybe somebody else will know.

**`vmstat 1`**
[image]

Comment: "us" == CPU running a user process. "sy" == CPU in kernel code. "id" == system is idle. "wa" == waiting for I/O. Does that help in grokking the vmstat output?

Comment: I think it does. Am I correct in assuming that each line in `vmstat` simply provides data about the last second, or whatever period provided? If so, it looks like my machine is idle most of the time, but also had a period where it was waiting for I/O in this screenshot?

Comment: Correct, and I agree with the interpretation.